# Confusion about $\epsilon$ in a proof about lower and upper Riemann integrals

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, epsilon-delta, riemann-integration

I'm trying to understand a proof about lower and upper Riemann integrals that has been covered during my lecture, but I'm stuck at the conclusion, since I'm apparently missing something about the use of $\epsilon$. It's probably something very stupid and obvious, but I still don't get it.

We want to prove that for all bounded functions $f, g : [a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have:
$$\int_a^{b*} (f+g)(x) dx \le \int_a^{b*}f(x)dx + \int_a^{b*}g(x)dx$$

where $$\int_a^{b*}f(x)dx := \inf\left\{ \int_a^b \psi(x) dx : \psi \in T([a,b]), \psi \ge f \right\} $$
and $T([a,b])$ is the set of all step functions $h:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

**The proof is the following:** (I'll write it exactly as it is written in my lecture)

Let $\epsilon > 0$. $\Rightarrow \exists$ $\psi_0$, $\psi_1 \in T([a,b])$ such that $\psi_0 \ge f$, $\psi_1 \ge g$ and

$$\int_a^b \psi_0 (x) dx \le \int_a^{b*}f(x) dx + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$
$$\int_a^b \psi_1 (x) dx \le \int_a^{b*}g(x) dx + \frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$\Rightarrow \psi:= \psi_0 + \psi_1 \in T([a,b])$ and $\psi = \psi_0 + \psi_1 \ge f+g$ (because of a lemma we covered before)
$$\Rightarrow \int_a^{b*} (f+g)(x)dy \le \int_a^b \psi(x) dx = \int_a^b \psi_0(x) dx + \int_a^b\psi_1(x)dx$$ $$\le \int_a^{b*}f(x)dx + \int_a^{b*}g(x)dx + \epsilon$$

**So far I think I understood everything. But here is the last sentence of the proof, and that's what I don't understand:**

arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$  $\Rightarrow$ $\int_a^{b*} (f+g)(x) dx \le \int_a^{b*}f(x)dx + \int_a^{b*}g(x)dx$.

...and I feel so sorry while writing this because I know how stupid it is to not understand such a thing, but here is what I don't get: we have:

$$\int_a^{b*}(f+g)(x)dx \le \int_a^{b*}f(x)dx + \int_a^{b*}g(x)dx + \epsilon$$

And let's say that the left part of that thing is $A$, and the right part is $B+\epsilon$. So we have $A \le B+\epsilon$.

We want to show that $A \le B$.

But all we know is that:
$$A-\epsilon \le A \le A+\epsilon$$
$$B-\epsilon \le B \le B+\epsilon$$
$$A \le B+\epsilon \text{ (so } A-\epsilon \le B)$$

So why should we have automatically $A\le B$, even for a very small $\epsilon$? Why couldn't we have $B \le A$? What does "arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$" mean? Shouldn't we have the result for any $\epsilon > 0$, not only small ones?

Again, I'm really sorry if my question sounds stupid. I already looked for other posts on stackexchange about that subject but nothing really convinced me. I found this post: [The method of proving the equality of integrals by showing they agree within $\epsilon$, for an arbitrary $\epsilon>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/823681/the-method-of-proving-the-equality-of-integrals-by-showing-they-agree-within-e) and I tried to understand the theorem that Sudarsan mentioned but I felt like the theorem was wrong (and I've not been able to prove it... I'm really going to lose my mind on that thing.)

So... any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you very much in advance. :)

EDIT: After some more hours of research, I managed to find a "proof" (which, I hope, is correct) for the following statement: Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$. If $c>a$ for all $c>b$, then $a \le b$. But I'm still upset about the $\le$ that appears in the precedent proof, and I'm still confused about all this. I'll try to give more details tomorrow, especially if there's still no answer or comment until then.

Comment: Since it holds for arbitrary $\epsilon>0$ just take the limit of both sides as $\epsilon \to 0^+$

Comment: Because epsilon was picked to be an arbitrary positive number, it means it holds for **all** positive epsilon.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's exactly what is bothering me: why picking an arbitrary positive number (even $\epsilon \rightarrow 0_{+}$ should mean that the result will hold for all greater positive epsilon than the one we picked?
What I mean is: we could have $A \le B + \epsilon$ with $A=2$, $B=1.5$ and $\epsilon = 0.5$. This inequality holds, but we have that $B \le A$, not $A \le B$.

Comment: Right, but it doesn't just hold for large epsilon. It holds for every epsilon. Even for epsilon that are arbitrarily small. It's not just one fixed epsilon. It holds for $\epsilon = 1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001$ etc. The only way this is possible is if $A \leq B$.

Comment: Apparently I'm missing something about the definition of limits, because in my head, for any $\epsilon$, even very small (like $\epsilon = 0.000001$, we could still find a $B=0.999999$ such that $A=1$ is greater than $B$... argh. I guess I will have to accept that, but I'm going to give another try to prove the theorem proposed by Sudarsan on the page I mentioned in my question. Maybe I'll understand this way... Thank you a lot for your answer :)

Comment: Right, but in the case you've described, in the limit, you would need to take $B=0.\bar{9}=1/3+1/3+1/3=1$. I'm just trying to give some intuition for the result, it is of course, a result that must be formally understood in the limiting case.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer. I finally found a more formal way to prove that thing (without using limits), so I'll just take it until the day I'll finally understand what exactly limits are (which will come soon, I hope).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A \leq B + \epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, it must be true that $A \leq B$. Otherwise, just take any $\epsilon >0$ such that $\epsilon < (A-B) $. This particular $\epsilon$ satisfies $B + \epsilon < A$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for your help ; however I don't really understand your proof. We want to show that $A \le B + \epsilon \Rightarrow A \le B$, so assuming the opposite is true, we should try to prove: $A \le B + \epsilon \Rightarrow A > B$. I feel like what you tried to prove by contradiction is $A > B + \epsilon \Rightarrow A > B$... or did you try to prove the contraposition? I'm confused.

Comment: I used a proof by contradiction. We're not trying to prove that $A \leq B + \epsilon \Rightarrow A > B$ (since that is impossible). What I did was show you get a contradiction in the hypothesis if you assume the incorrect conclusion $A > B$ is true. Namely, that it is possible to find an $\epsilon > 0$ that contradicts the hypothesis $A \leq B + \epsilon$. I thought of this proof by picturing what it would look like on a number line. Imagine two points $A > B$ on a number line, with some distance in between them. If you choose $\epsilon$ smaller than this distance, you get $B + \epsilon < A$.

Comment: So this is the same thing I finally found by myself. Thanks for the clarification and sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally found something that convinced me, so here it is in case it could be useful for someone else:

We want to prove that $\forall \epsilon >0, A \le B+\epsilon \Rightarrow A \le B$. Let's suppose the opposite is true, i.e. $A > B.$

We have $A > B \Leftrightarrow B = A - c$, with $c > 0$.

$\Leftrightarrow B+c = A$.

Let $\epsilon = \frac{c}{2}$. We still have $\epsilon > 0$, since $c>0$. By assumption, $A \le B + \epsilon = B + \frac{c}{2}$

But $B+c = A \le B+\frac{c}{2}$,

i.e. $B+c \le B + \frac{c}{2}$, which is a contradiction. Therefore, $A \le B$.

Comment: Yes, though note this is effectively the same argument that @ryanw. put forth. I would suggest you revisit his answer and convince yourself that they are equivalent.

Comment: I just noticed that. Seems like my IQ is below sea level. Still hope this thing can be improved and not stay that low.
Anyway, thanks a lot for the help and have a nice day! :)

Comment: No reason to feel bad about it. Math is hard. What seems easy for others is likely that way because they've already spent many hours figuring out what you're learning now. Take care!